# why a Label control's text property is not set inside the Page_Load event handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

**Mark Up:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Files.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebModules.Web.Files" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Status" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;

namespace WebModules.Web
{
    public partial class Files : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Status.Text="Hello";
        }

        private void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the page in a browser the text "Hello" is not shown on the label.

Does anyone know why this doesn't function?

Comment: Why have you changed the page initialization cycle?!

Comment: @AndreCalil please answer to the point

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud But probably **that's** the problem. Remove `Page_Init` and `InitializeComponent` methods, let the lifecycle flow it's defaults and tell me if it's working.

Comment: @AndreCalil nope! its not working

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud `Page_Load` must not be **private**. Again: why have you changed it?

Comment: @AndreCalil I tried with all possible specifiers, yet the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try changing the access modifiers on your methods from **private** to **protected**:

```
//I'm assuming that Files is the class of your page, and not just another class. Make sure that your markup inherits from this class
public partial class Files : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Status.Text="Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud The answer is updated. Make sure that the class `File` is at the file `CodeBehind="BrowseFiles.aspx.cs"`

Comment: made sure, but result is the same

Comment: I have fixed it ! I've just changed the attribute AutoEventWireup="false" to AutoEventWireup="true". it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted your label and pageload code into my current application and it displays fine.

Do this:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
Status.Text="Hello";          
}
```

then place the labe ID in your source code:

```
<asp:Label ID="Status" runat="server" />
```

Comment: did you place this in your query page? If so, place it in your default.aspx.cs instead

Comment: I have fixed it ! I've just changed the attribute AutoEventWireup="false" to AutoEventWireup="true". it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it ! I've just changed the attribute `AutoEventWireup="false"` to `AutoEventWireup="true"`. it works fine now